# Html.DropDownListFor not working for specific list in specific view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I use this method in my controller to add some lists to ViewBag which is used by two actions: `Create` and `Edit`. The lists are properly set, some items have set `Selected` property true.

```
    private void AddUsersAndTrucksListsToViewBag(string[] selectedUsers, int[] selectedTrucks)
    {
        ViewBag.UsersList = uow.UsersRepository
            .GetAll(_siteId)
            .Where(u => u.IsActive)
            .Select(u => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = u.Id,
                Text = $"{u.Name} {u.Surname}",
                Selected = selectedUsers != null && selectedUsers.Contains(u.Id)
            })
            .ToArray();

        ViewBag.TrucksList = uow.OspRepository
            .GetAllTrucks(_siteId)
            .Select(t => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = t.Id.ToString(),
                Text = $"{t.Codename} {t.Manufacturer} {t.Model}",
                Selected = selectedTrucks != null && selectedTrucks.Contains(t.Id)
            })
            .ToArray();
    }
```

In `Edit` view:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Osoby", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedUserIds, (SelectListItem[])ViewBag.UsersList, new { @class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Samochody", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedTruckIds, (SelectListItem[]) ViewBag.TrucksList, new {@class = "form-control", multiple = "multiple"})
        </div>
    </div>
```

And exactly the same in `Create` view:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Osoby", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedUserIds, (SelectListItem[])ViewBag.UsersList, new { @class = "form-control ", multiple = "multiple" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Samochody", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedTruckIds, (SelectListItem[]) ViewBag.TrucksList, new {@class = "form-control ", multiple = "multiple"})
        </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is that everything works fine in `Edit` view. But in `Create` view only second list has properly rendered `selected` HTML attributes. This can be seen on the screenshots

[image: Everything is fine in the viewbags]
[image: But only items on second list are selected]

What's wrong with this? I found that it can be caused by having the same `ViewBag` property name as some of `Model` property name but it is not.
Both lists have `multiple` attribute.

This is HTML generated by `ListBoxFor()`

```
<select class="form-control " id="SelectedUserIds" multiple="multiple" name="SelectedUserIds">
<option value="525b1890-942f-4fb4-96de-56e04b6ca196">Jan Kowalski</option>
<option value="5b0e1c01-0e46-436c-aa9b-ac63e66d691f">Adam Pawlak</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control " id="SelectedTruckIds" multiple="multiple" name="SelectedTruckIds">
<option selected="selected" value="3">425[O]21 MAN 12.232</option>
</select>
```

New screenshots:
[image: selected ids in model]
[image: html generated]

Comment: Do not use `DropDownListFor()` with `multiple` - use `ListBoxFor()` which correctly generates a `<select multiple="multiple">`. Note also there is no point setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` - its ignored by the DropDownListFor() and ListBoxFor()` methods (its the value of the property your binding to which determines what is selected)

Comment: `DropDownList` creates select tag for single selected option only, as expected with plain drop down menu. `ListBoxFor` is more suitable way to bind list models with multiple selected values passed as array.

Comment: @StephenMuecke so I changed to `ListBoxFor()` and assigned the selected values to `Model` properties and it is still not working, only the second list have properly selected values. And as I noticed, everything works fine in other view, which has exactly the same dropdowns

Comment: It can only mean that `SelectedUserIds` is not a collection containing any of the `Guid` values that match the values of the options

Comment: @StephenMuecke But it is, check out the screenshots

Comment: No, your screen shot is showing the values of the `ViewBag` property. As I noted before, the `Selected` property of your `SelectList` is ignored. Internally the `ListBoxFor()` and `DropDownListFor()` methods generate a  new `SelectList` and set the `Selected` properties based on the values in the property your binding to.

Comment: I not going to go through all those :), but assuming `SelectedUserIds` does contain values which match some of the option values, then you need to show your GET method (the `HtmlHelper` first check `ModelState`, then the`ViewDataDictionary` and only if there are no matching values in those, it finally checks the values in the property.